# Maya Python Script - os.popen tasklist read Is super slow. Faster way?

Tags: python, import, maya, tasklist

I'm checking os tasklist to find out if an external app is running or not. The script is run through python & maya. This command takes more than 10 seconds which seems very slow to fetch a list of strings? How can I speed up this process?

```
# python
import os
import maya.cmds as cmds

def getTasks(name):
    r = os.popen('tasklist /v').read().strip().split('\n')
    for i in range(len(r)):
        s = r[i]
        if name in r[i]:
            return True
    return False

if getTasks("program.exe") == False:
    cmds.confirmDialog( title='program.exe Not Running', message='program.exe is not running and action will not be executed.')
```

Comment: It takes about .33 sec with 186 processes on my Windows10 machine with your code. Does it take the same time if you execute the tasklist command from commandline?

Comment: Good idea. I tried in cmd and it took 0.55 sec for me. Tried it in maya and that took 10 times as long 5.5 sec. I'll make a post on autodesk maya forum and see if they have an answer for me.

Comment: I got help on the autodesk forums! The trick was using subprocess instead of os! Not sure if I can post links here but here is the title on atuodesk maya forums "Python get os tasklist takes 20 times longer through maya vs cmd. Solution?"